# SetWindowsHookEx is always returning zero in C#

Tags: c#, setwindowshookex

I'm trying to hook a 3rd party app so that I can interact with the controls. But I am having issues with using `SetWindowsHookEx` to handle `WH_KEYBOARD`. It seems there is some problem with parameters that I am passing to `SetWindowsHookEx`.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private delegate int HookProc(int code, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
    static IntPtr hHook;
    IntPtr windowHandle;
    uint processHandle;

    HookProc PaintHookProcedure;

    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "FindWindow", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern System.IntPtr FindWindowByCaption(int ZeroOnly, string lpWindowName);

    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SetWindowsHookEx", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook, HookProc lpfn, IntPtr hMod, uint dwThreadId);

    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern int CallNextHookEx(IntPtr hhk, int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    // When you don't want the ProcessId, use this overload and pass IntPtr.Zero for the second parameter
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern uint GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr hWnd, out uint lpdwProcessId);

    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = System.Runtime.InteropServices.CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern IntPtr GetModuleHandle(string lpModuleName);

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        PaintHookProcedure = new HookProc(PaintHookProc);
        windowHandle = FindWindowByCaption(0, "Untitled - Notepad");
        uint threadID = GetWindowThreadProcessId(windowHandle, out processHandle);
        IntPtr hMod = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetHINSTANCE(typeof(Form1).Module);

        // HERE IS THE PROBLEM.  It returns always zero. No matter what parameters you pass.
        hHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD, PaintHookProcedure, hMod, threadID);


    }

    public int PaintHookProc(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
    {
        // Do something here
        return CallNextHookEx(hHook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
    }

    private const int WH_KEYBOARD = 2;

}
```

Above is the sample code. `SetWindowsHookEx` is returning always zero.
Any suggestions would be very helpful.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: "If the function fails, the return value is `NULL`. To get extended error information, call `GetLastError`." In C#, the easier way to do that is `throw new Win32Exception()`, which will automatically call GLE. You usually get back nothing more informative than "invalid parameter", but at least that's *something*.

Comment: While you're at it, read the [rest of the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/ms644990), specifically the restrictions on the parameters when you're trying to hook a procedure in a different process. Your process is not a DLL and it can't be injected into a remote process' address space.

Comment: @Jeroen I used `GetLastError' and got below error,   **ERROR_HOOK_NEEDS_HMOD
1428 (0x594)
Cannot set nonlocal hook without a module handle.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you look at this page: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/318804/how-to-set-a-windows-hook-in-visual-c--net ?

Your Dllimports are subtly different

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SetWindowsHookEx", SetLastError = true)]
static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook, HookProc lpfn, IntPtr hMod, uint dwThreadId);
```

vs

```
[DllImport("user32.dll",CharSet=CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention=CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public static extern int SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook, HookProc lpfn, IntPtr hInstance, int threadId);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Still It's not working after i modified the `DLLImport` statement. And I have gone through the link that you mentioned in the answer. It's working fine if `dwThreadId` parameter specifies a thread created by the current process. And it's failing if I pass some other process thread id as `dwThreadId`.

Comment: That's a security thing.  You aren't allowed to inject your hook into someone else's process.

Comment: Out of curiosity I am asking Is there any way to achieve this without writing unmanaged code and using it's DLL?

Comment: Are you running visual studio as an administrator?

Comment: What is it you are actually trying to do? You have a solution (hooking a keyboard to control another app) but haven't really told us why you want to do it.  Are you trying to do testing of the other app?  TestStacks.White is a library that you can use to write C# code to drive another application.  Selenium can be used to drive a web site.

Comment: Yes, I am running visual studio as an administrator. I am not trying to do the testing of the other app. I do have a requirement, where I need to take the data enter by the user in other application and process that data in my application.